# Make a new table that shows only certain cells from a reference table according to their values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a of monthly expenses spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
Rent     | $200 | +10% (variation from this value to the past month value)
Internet | $60  | -5%
Fuel     | $100 | +12%
```

... and so on.

As there are several categories, what I'd like to do is to make a new table that would show only those categories for which the variation was higher than a certain value, like 20%, to know where my expenses raised too much.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

### Sounds like a job for Pivot Table!

<sub>*click any image to view full size*</sub>

Select your data and go to *insert → pivot table*

Then set up your table like this -

[image]

You can see I'm filtering the pivot table based on *Variation* and I'm using *multiple items*

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this could be done more simply with just

#### Filters

<sub>*click any image to view full size*</sub>

Select your data and go to *home → editing → sort & filter* and select **Filter**

Then click on the filter for variation and go to number filters - greater than...

[image]

Then enter your desired filter -

[image]

And voila

[image]